# curved Vector Drawable not getting full width

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Hi i am developing an app where i'm using vector drawable to create custom shapes however my problem is that the first shape is not getting created and second shape is getting created properly but not getting full width 
Here is my current [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D8P0.jpg)
and Here is what i'm trying to [achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqC9n.jpg)
Please any help would be appreciated

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ct.listrtrial.fragments.ProfileFragment">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_first_image"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_second_image"/>
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ellipse2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/pencil"/>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my two vector drawables

profile_first_image.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="248dp"
    android:height="148dp"
    android:viewportHeight="12"
    android:viewportWidth="12">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#f1c40f"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 0,11 C 1,12 5,12 8,12 C 12,12 12,11 12,11 L 12,0 0,0"
        android:strokeWidth="0.1"/>

</vector>
```

profile_second_image.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="15dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: why dont you use `<vector>` with two `<path>`s inside (for white and yellow shape)?

Comment: Hi @pskink can you show me how because with first vector im not getting proper curve

Comment: use `inkscape` and design your shape, save to .svg file then import in android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_first_image">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_first_image"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/second_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_second_image" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/goku3" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="146dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
            android:src="@drawable/kid_goku" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> **android:src="@drawable/profile_second_image"**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="15dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

> **android:src="@drawable/profile_first_image"**

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="248dp"
    android:height="148dp"
    android:viewportHeight="12"
    android:viewportWidth="12">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#f1c40f"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 0,8 C 1,12 5,12 8,12 C 10,12 12,11 15,1 L 12,0 0,0"
        android:strokeWidth="0.1"/>

</vector>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nilesh but how can i make he background fully curve as in the image https://imgur.com/a/KmpR3LY

Comment: @john check updated ans i have made changes in `profile_first_image` vector hope this help s